# One set of training samples for multiple segmentation rasters

Tags: arcgis-pro, segment

Can I create one set of training samples (~800 training polygons) that can be used for many segmented rasters if the training sample polygon match across segmented raster (6-8 rasters total), or is there a way to creat a single training sample file and loading it into the training sample manager using each segmented raster and making it acknowledged the different raster and adjust training variables?

I am working on a project that has 3-4 segmented rasters from two different sets of imagery (single pass and grid drone flights) to test different segmentation parameters and flight patterns for image classification.